# SELECT 2 tables with CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 2 tables **Sales** and **Seller**

**What I have :**

```
$this->set('mysales', $this->Sales->find('all', 
  array(
     'fields' => array('price','seller_number','buyer_number'),
     'group' => array('seller_number','buyer_number')
  )
));
```

*price*, *seller_number* and *buyer_number* are in the **Sales** table.

**What I want :**

I want to display in the same query the *seller_name* and the *seller_address* which are in the **Seller** table.

If it was in the same table I just have to add *seller_name* and *seller_address* in *fields* but in other table I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. As I didn't implement the database myself I didn't notice that the models weren't linked.

So I just put *$hasmany* in the **Seller** model and a *$belongTo* in the **Sales** model and rewrote the query like that :

```
$this->set('mysales', $this->Sales->find('all', 
  array(
     'fields' => array('price','Sales.seller_number','Sales.buyer_number','Seller.name','Seller.address'),
     'group' => array('Sales.seller_number','Sales.buyer_number''Seller.name','Seller.address')
  )
));
```